# How to call a function after running winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am built same win Form  that opens some website with webBrowser after this i need to run runMyfunction,but this doesn't happens.

Then i run runMyfunction, all stops and when i debug it it stays on

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

What i am missing here? This my code :

```
namespace UmbWin
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //I tried this also
            //Form1 myForm = new Form1();
            //myForm.Show();
            //myForm.runMyfunction()- doesn't do anything

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }  
    }
}
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
[STAThread]
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string authHeader = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";
    webBrowser.Navigate("https://www.test.com/Default.aspx", null, null, authHeader);

    runMyfunction();
}      
public void runMyfunction()
{
    //here where it stops and does nothing
    HtmlElement head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("123");
    HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use *Form_Closed*(Form_Closing) event : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I need to run this function while the webBrowser is running ,not when i close the app

Comment: Aside from your current problem (by the way "all stops" is not a very descriptive definition) - it looks like you have to move your call to `runMyFunction` into `DocumentCompleted` event handler of webbrowser. Otherwise it can be run before document in webbrowser will be completely loaded.

Comment: `// here it stops and does nothing`: looks like exception happens when form is loading and there is a known issue of such cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `Application.Run` will only complete once the main form of the application is closed.

`Application.Run` runs the message loop (it checks for clicks and other Windows events. Read up on how Windows / Win32 works if you don't know what this all means). It is meant to run forever.

Your `runMyfunction` will only run once after the `Navigate` call. That's all. If you want to run it after every navigate, subscribe to the [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event.